# Shell - how to extract and substitute values from a file in a for loop

Tags: shell, docker, for-loop, sh

I'm writing the sample script which will collect the logs from docker containers.
The containers are running .NET Core applications (*.dll files) and log files are written to the same directory (where assembly file is located) using Nlog.

```
  #!/bin/bash

DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
LOGPATH="/var/log/kbci-ocr"
LOGDIR="${LOGPATH}/LOG-${DATE}"
LOGERR="${LOGDIR}/err.log"

docker ps --format {{.ID}},{{.Image}} > docker_running.txt
file=docker_running.txt
for i in `cat $file`
do
    echo "Checking log dir presence"
    if [ ! -d $LOGDIR ]; then
        mkdir -p $LOGDIR;
        echo "Log dir created"
    else
        echo "Log dir exist"
    fi
    echo "Creating log dir for the current log saving iteration"
    container=$(echo $i | cut -d"," -f1)
    TARGETDIR="${LOGDIR}/${container}+$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)"
    mkdir -p $TARGETDIR
    echo "Copying log files from container ${container}"
    imagename=$(echo $i | cut -d"," -f2 | cut -d"/" -f4 | cut -d":" -f1)
    docker cp ${container}:/app/'\${imagename}_app.json' ${TARGETDIR}
    docker cp ${container}:/app/'\${imagename}_errors.json' ${TARGETDIR}
    docker cp ${container}:/app/'\${imagename}_sql.json' ${TARGETDIR}
    docker cp ${container}:/app/'\${imagename}_webHost.json' ${TARGETDIR}
done

rm -rf docker_running.txt
```

What the script should do:

1. Check the XXX directory presence in /var/log, create if doesn't exist
2. Create a new directory in /var/log/XXX according to today's date
3. For each docker container running, create a directory inside the base (see p.2) directory  using the container hash (first value from the text file) and timestamp
4. Copy log files from the container file system using the `docker cp` command and the container's image name (second value from the text file)

Here I have a problem - how to grab the second value from the text file and substitute it in the shell script?

The sample output of docker placed to file is:

```
sergey@023:~$ cat docker_running.txt
b0a6dbb31f4e,ecse00:5000/develop/client-api:latest
d80f5e5a2cf5,ecse00:5000/develop/document-uploader:latest
965e9b40a8d0,ecse00:5000/develop/data-analysis:latest
ef8a6bad36a7,ecse00:5000/develop/job-aggregator:latest
be4ccd899a61,ecse00:5000/develop/capture-plugin:latest
```

First is container ID, second (after the colon) is an image name + tag with docker registry address preceding.

I've tried a lot of options but still no idea how to correctly write the script.

**Upd:** The script seems to be working, the last question is how to substitute the image name to `docker cp` command:

```
sergey@ECSE00:~$ sh collect_logs.sh
Checking log dir presence
Log dir created
Creating log dir for the current log saving iteration
Copying log files from container f44d14d08b61

Error: No such container:path: f44d14d08b61:/app/\${imagename@Q}_app.json
Error: No such container:path: f44d14d08b61:/app/\${imagename@Q}_errors.json
Error: No such container:path: f44d14d08b61:/app/\${imagename@Q}_sql.json
Error: No such container:path: f44d14d08b61:/app/\${imagename@Q}_webHost.json
Checking log dir presence
Log dir exist
Creating log dir for the current log saving iteration
Copying log files from container 13f0069c207a
client-api
Error: No such container:path: 13f0069c207a:/app/\${imagename@Q}_app.json
Error: No such container:path: 13f0069c207a:/app/\${imagename@Q}_errors.json
Error: No such container:path: 13f0069c207a:/app/\${imagename@Q}_sql.json
Error: No such container:path: 13f0069c207a:/app/\${imagename@Q}_webHost.json
Checking log dir presence
Log dir exist
Creating log dir for the current log saving iteration
Copying log files from container 8ff648fa8b04
document-uploader
Error: No such container:path: 8ff648fa8b04:/app/\${imagename@Q}_app.json
Error: No such container:path: 8ff648fa8b04:/app/\${imagename@Q}_errors.json
Error: No such container:path: 8ff648fa8b04:/app/\${imagename@Q}_sql.json
Error: No such container:path: 8ff648fa8b04:/app/\${imagename@Q}_webHost.json
Checking log dir presence
Log dir exist
Creating log dir for the current log saving iteration
Copying log files from container 1ee8ad5cab31
data-analysis
Error: No such container:path: 1ee8ad5cab31:/app/\${imagename@Q}_app.json
Error: No such container:path: 1ee8ad5cab31:/app/\${imagename@Q}_errors.json
Error: No such container:path: 1ee8ad5cab31:/app/\${imagename@Q}_sql.json
Error: No such container:path: 1ee8ad5cab31:/app/\${imagename@Q}_webHost.json
Checking log dir presence
Log dir exist
Creating log dir for the current log saving iteration
Copying log files from container 53a8467cd7f6
job-aggregator
Error: No such container:path: 53a8467cd7f6:/app/\${imagename@Q}_app.json
Error: No such container:path: 53a8467cd7f6:/app/\${imagename@Q}_errors.json
Error: No such container:path: 53a8467cd7f6:/app/\${imagename@Q}_sql.json
Error: No such container:path: 53a8467cd7f6:/app/\${imagename@Q}_webHost.json
```

Comment: check `docker ps -q` if you want to get the ids of running containers

Comment: Read this about reading the fields from a file: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Given the first line from the "running" file, what should this command look like: `docker cp $i:/app/'\$j_app.json' $TARGETDIR` ??

Comment: @user2915097 Unfortunately, I require not only numeric IDs but the image name also.

Comment: @glennjackman I've updated my question. The idea for the aforementioned string is to copy log file (\$j_app.json) from the container to the recently created directory ($TARGETDIR). The log file format is a bit bugged (the file is saved as \container_app.json - that's the next step for refactoring) so I've escaped it properly.

Comment: Please answer the question. What do you want for `$i` and what for `$j`?

Comment: As you can see there is no more $i and $j. I've reworked the question and the code. However, $i should mean container hash and $j - container image name variables.

Answer (score 0):

The final (working) version will be like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
LOGPATH="/var/log/kbci-ocr"
LOGDIR="${LOGPATH}/LOG-${DATE}"
LOGERR="${LOGDIR}/err.log"

docker ps --format {{.ID}},{{.Image}} > docker_running.txt
file=docker_running.txt
for i in `cat $file`
do
        echo "Checking log dir presence"
        if [ ! -d $LOGDIR ]
        then
                mkdir -p $LOGDIR
                echo "Log dir created"
        else
                echo "Log dir exist"
        fi
        echo "Creating log dir for the current log saving iteration"
        container=$(echo $i | cut -d"," -f1)
        TARGETDIR="${LOGDIR}/${container}_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)"
        mkdir -p $TARGETDIR
        imagename=$(echo $i | cut -d"," -f2 | cut -d"/" -f4 | cut -d":" -f1)
        echo "Copying log files from container ${container} \ image ${imagename} to path ${TARGETDIR}"
        if [ "$imagename" = "client-api" ]
        then
                $(docker cp ${container}:/app/\\${imagename}_app.json $TARGETDIR)
                $(docker cp ${container}:/app/\\${imagename}_errors.json $TARGETDIR)
                $(docker cp ${container}:/app/\\${imagename}_sql.json $TARGETDIR)
                $(docker cp ${container}:/app/\\${imagename}_webHost.json $TARGETDIR)
        elif [ "$imagename" = "data-analysis" ]
        then
                $(docker cp ${container}:/app/\\${imagename}_app.json $TARGETDIR)
                $(docker cp ${container}:/app/\\${imagename}_sql.json $TARGETDIR)
        elif [ "$imagename" = "job-aggregator" ]
        then
                $(docker cp ${container}:/app/\\${imagename}_app.json $TARGETDIR)
                $(docker cp ${container}:/app/\\${imagename}_mt.json $TARGETDIR)
        elif [ "$imagename" = "document-uploader" ]
        then
                $(docker cp ${container}:/app/\\${imagename}_app.json $TARGETDIR)
        elif [ "$imagename" = "capture-plugin" ]
        then
                $(docker cp ${container}:/app/\\${imagename}_app.json $TARGETDIR)
                $(docker cp ${container}:/app/\\${imagename}_mt.json $TARGETDIR)
                $(docker cp ${container}:/app/\\${imagename}_sql.json $TARGETDIR)
        fi
done

rm -rf docker_running.txt
```